# Encode error with Java EE 7 for Javax.mail.message

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jakarta-mail

In the older version of Java EE we could set encode for javax.mail.message like this:

```
message.setSubject("my subjects", "utf-8")
```

But now we are using java sdk 1.8 (java ee 7). There is only one method:

```
message.setSubject("my subjects");
```

We can not specify which encode here.  How can i configure the encoding for java ee 7?

Comment: Not so in the javadoc for [Java EE 7](https://javaee-spec.java.net/nonav/javadocs/index.html?overview-summary.html) - MimeMessage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `setSubject(String subject, String charset)` is changed to the `MimeMessage` class.It is not part of the Message class.

So, changing:

```
Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
```

To

```
MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
```

should solve your issue.